# How to enforce a single line using Regex?

Tags: c#, regex, string, multiline

I need a [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object that will reject any string that spreads across multiple lines.

I want this to succeed:

```
"This is my string"
```

And this to fail:

```
"This is my string" + Environment.NewLine + "that spreads acrosss" + Environment.NewLine + "multiple lines."
```

I have been reading on the [documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Singleline) and assumed the following should work:

- Regular expression pattern: `"^.+"`
- *Regex* object initialized with this pattern, WITHOUT any options (no `RegexOptions.Singleline` or `RegexOptions.Multiline`).

When testing with multiple line strings, the *Regex.IsMatch* method always return true. 
I believe it is because *IsMatch* will return true when there is at least a portion of the string that matches the pattern.

In my case, anything prior to a new line will cause a match. The only way this will fail is if the string only has line breaks and no other char.

Is there a *Regex* validation method that will consider the string as a whole, instead of splitting it in matching sub-strings? I suspect I probably need a more complex string pattern to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this regex to match only single line:

```
^[^\r\n]+$
```

And you need not use `RegexOptions.Multiline` with this regex.

Comment: Thanks anubhava. It works as expected. I was hoping that an "accept all" pattern could have been used combined with RegexOptions to drive the Multiline or Singleline criteria. I got mislead by the names.